# Сохранение страницы html для чтобы потом отображать Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, кэширование

Хочу получить поисковый запрос гугла , а результат выдачи сохранить , чтобы потом данные парсить офлайн. Как это сделать лучше ? Может лучше просто сохранять страницу в кэш? Покажите пожалуйста легкий пример на Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить можно где угодно главное чтобы памяти хватило.

```
<?php
...
$uri
    = 'https://www.google.com/search?ei=TuwSXNzrG5CdkgXwvZSIBQ&q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&oq=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.22955.25291..25435...1.0..3.141.1671.0j13......0....1..gws-wiz.....6..35i39j0i10i1j0i10.VbUmnJbYTqA';
//echo file_get_contents($uri);
$key        = sha1($uri);
$minutes    = 24 * 60;
$googlePage = Cache::remember($key, $minutes, function () use ($uri) {
    return file_get_contents($uri);
});
```